# A strategy for a basic combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

Given the set $A=\left\{2;\:3;\:4;\:5;\:6;\:7;\:8;\:9\right\}$, how many five digit, odd, distinct, numbers can we construct with the elements of $A$, that are also less than $49999$.

Here's how I tried to solved it:

> If $9$ is in the units, 2 or 3 must be in the tenths of thousands. Two numbers selected out of eight, there remains six numbers for three places (between the units and the tens of thousands). Therefore: $2\cdot_6P_3$
>
> If $3$ is in the units place, two choices remain for the tens of thousands. Again: $2\cdot_6P_3$
>
> If $5$ or $7$ are in the units, there can be three numbers in the tens of thousands ($2$, $3$, or $4$). Then, there are still six numbers remaining to chose. Therefore: $2\cdot3\cdot_6P_3$
>
> The number of combinations shoulb be given by $2\cdot_6P_3+2\cdot_6P_3+2\cdot3\cdot_6P_3=1200$

This solution is wrong, and I can figure out why.

Comment: "algorisms"????

Comment: Algorisms?  Do you mean to ask "*How many odd five-digit integers less than $49999$ can we construct using these elements?*"  Are you allowed to repeat digits?  The final answer will change based on whether you can or can't repeat.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, got lost in translation. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are not allowed to repeat digits in the number: for example $33333$ doesn't count as a valid odd five-digit number less than $49999$ made from the available digits.

---

We know that the first digit (*in the ten-thousands place*) must be a $2,3,$ or $4$ in order to satisfy the condition that the result is less than $49999$.  Break into cases.

Once having done so, pick the final digit next (*in the units place*).  It must be an odd digit from those remaining (*note that if $3$ was selected for the first digit then this affects the count*)

Once having done so, finally fill in the remaining digits from left to right with any still available to choose from.

- If the first digit is even, i.e. it is a $2$ or a $4$, pick which one it is  (2 options)

  - The final digit is odd, pick which it is (4 options)
  - Pick the second, third, and fourth digits (6, 5, and 4 options each respectively)
- If the first digit was odd, then it must have been a $3$ (1 option)

  - The final digit is odd, pick which it is (3 options)
  - Pick the second, third, and fourth digits (6, 5, and 4 options each respectively)

This gives a total of $2\times 4\times 6\times 5\times 4 + 1\times 3\times 6\times 5\times 4 = 1320$

---

Your error appears to be in the line "*If $9$ is in the units, 2 or 3 must be in the tenths of thousands*"

Note that the number $45679$ is a valid number which ends in a nine and yet begins with a $4$.  You neglected to take $4$ into consideration as a possible leading digit when $9$ is the final digit.

Answer (score 0):

You considered all $4$ cases on the units (last) digit being odd.

Alternatively, you can consider $2$ cases ($[\ ]$ is the specific digit of the $5$-digit number):

Case 1: $[2 \ or \ 4][\  ][\ ][\ ][3] \Rightarrow 2\cdot P(6,3)=2\cdot 120=240;$

Case 2: $[2 \ or \ 3 \ or \ 4][\  ][\ ][\ ][5 \ or \ 7 \ or \ 9] \Rightarrow 3\cdot 3\cdot P(6,3)=3\cdot 3\cdot 120=1080.$

Hence, the number of favorable numbers is: $240+1080=1320$.

Yes, as noted by JMoravitz, you missed $\color{red}4[\ ][\ ][\ ][9]$ in the first case: hence, you must have $\color{red}3\cdot_6P_3$.